# Why won't this PostGIS query display in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, postgis

I am having trouble rendering the following PostGIS query in qgis1.803.

```
SELECT
s.musym,
st_intersection(s.the_geom,f.the_geom) as geo,
nextval('"soilsplittersequence"'::regclass) as k
From public."SoilsSpatial" as s JOIN public."Fields" as f 
ON ST_Intersects(s.the_geom, f.the_geom) 
where f."FarmNumber"=37
```

When I run this query in the db manager module it returns 500 ish results, but I can't display it.   I also can't display this query if I use it to create a view in my postgis database.

The only way I can get it to display is if I make the query into a create table.

I'm assuming that the problem is related to my use of a sequence to generate a unique id.  The reason that I'm using this technique is that there is a many to many relationship between the two tables.

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: What happens when you try and view it in QGIS as a live query? Do you get a error?

Comment: When I execute the query in the db Manager module of qgis I don't receive any error messages and get a full table of results, but when I try to load the results into the canvas I get:                       Fetching from cursor qgisf0 failed
Database error: ERROR:  cannot execute nextval() in a read-only transaction

Comment: The error makes sense.  I'm guessing DB Manager is only using read-only transactions but nextval() will change the database (increments the sequence).  You'll want to remove the nextval() and try again.

Comment: Do you need an integer id in the query?